# New Dell UltraSharp monitor flickering

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I recently bought a new Dell [U2312HM](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=320-2807) LED monitor and connected it to my laptop via the VGA cable that came with it. I’ve also installed the drivers

Now it’s flickering and the flickering becomes very obvious with darker backgrounds.

What could be the reason? Can someone help?

Comment: did you set a Refresh rate for the monitor? in **Resolution settings**, click on the monitor you want to change, and select **advanced settings** text there on that page, then go to the **monitor** tab  And check the **screen refresh rate**  It also could be a lesser quality or poorly connected VGA cable, or interferance from something.  If there was any way you could describe the type of flickering better it would help.

Comment: Try it on another system.

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit. Changed from VGA to DVI and it worked fine.